# How to calculate rotation position in Javascript

Tags: javascript

There is a picture with a width of 5 and a height of 10. The left top of this picture is located at (0,0) on the coordinate axis. There is an X coordinate point on the picture at the position of (1,1). Now we need to rotate the picture 90 degrees and find the new X coordinate point.

The rotation of the X coordinate has two requirements:
1、After rotation, the new left top of the image needs to be located at the position of (0,0), and the coordinate point also needs to be displaced.
2、Since the width is fixed, in the case of 90/270 degrees, the length of the image needs to be compressed on the basis of the length of 10, and the height is compressed to 2.5. At 180 degrees, it will recover, so the coordinates also need to be compressed.

[image]

this is my code

```
   const roatePos = this.positionRoate(ele.x, ele.y, centerX, centerY, roate) 
   const zeroPos = this.positionRoate(0, 0, centerX, centerY, roate) 
   const fixPos = this.fixPosition(zeroPos, roatePos)
   const scalePos = this.scalePosition(fixPos.x, fixPos.y, roate)

   scalePosition (x, y, angle) {
     const newImgWidth = this.$refs.mistakeImg[this.getCorrectIndex].width  //image has roated size
     const newImgHeight = this.$refs.mistakeImg[this.getCorrectIndex].height //image has roated size
     console.log('newImgWidth', newImgWidth)
     console.log('newImgHeight', newImgHeight)
     let scaleX = 0; let scaleY = 0
     scaleX = newImgHeight / this.lastestImageInfo.width //lastestImageInfo image unroated size
     scaleY = newImgWidth / this.lastestImageInfo.height //lastestImageInfo image unroated size
     console.log('scaleX, scaleY', scaleX, scaleY)
     return { x: x * scaleX, y: y * scaleY }
  }

   positionRoate (x, y, cx, cy, angle) {
     var radians = (Math.PI / 180) * -angle
     var cos = Math.cos(radians)
     var sin = Math.sin(radians)
     var nx = (cos * (x - cx)) + (sin * (y - cy)) + cx
     var ny = (cos * (y - cy)) - (sin * (x - cx)) + cy
     return { x: nx, y: ny }
   }

    fixPosition (fixPos, targetPos) {
        return { x: targetPos.x - fixPos.x, y: targetPos.y - fixPos.y }
    },
```

get a wrong result Why?